# How to sort a List of arrays by an element at a specified index in the array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

I have a list<> of int arrays created like this

```
List<uint[]> onMinterm = new List<uint[]>();
```

and it has got 1000 members. Every list members has 3 unsigned integers, I add my arrays just like that

```
uint[] sayi= new uint[3];    
sayi[0] = 34432; sayi[1] = 63533; sayi[2] = 12;    
onMinterm.Add(sayi);
```

I want to sort my 1000 list (`onMinterm`) according to each 3rd member (`sayi[2]`). List will be sorted in decending order. Sample member should be at the end as its 3rd value is very small like 12.

Comment: `onMinTerm.OrderByDescending(a => a[2]);`. That said, take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Design-wise you may want your uint[] to actually be a class or a struct.  If you regularly have exactly 3 of somethingand you have that many of them, it's sounding like the stuff in the uint may deserve to have its own identity--i.e., these regularly recurring  three values may have some related semantic value that deserves to be named and given their own identity an (possibly, via methods) functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to sort my 1000 list (`onMinterm`) according to each 3rd member (`sayi[2]`). List will be sorted descending.

You can do this, if you are ok with getting an `IOrderedEnumerable` as the result.

```
var ordered = onMinterm.OrderByDescending(x => x[2]);
```

If you want to do an in-place sort:

```
onMinterm.Sort((x1, x2)=> x2[2].CompareTo(x1[2]));
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I did not know how to do it this way (in place with Comparison delegate).

Answer (score 1):

You can sort a List<> in place.

```
    class IntArrayComparer : IComparer<int[]>
    {
      public int Compare(T left, T right)
      {
        return right[2].CompareTo(left[2]);
      }
    }

    myList.Sort(new IntArrayComparer());
```

Comment: Note that this will not result in a descending sort order as OP requested in his question.